# Pythontex Installation

Tags: pythontex

I am trying to install pythontex on my computer. I am using TeXstudio as my editor. I don't know if what I've done so far is correct, and how much more I need to do.

So far, I've downloaded these packages, per the manual's instructions: fancyvrb, fvextra, etoolbox, xstring, pgfplots, newfloat, currfile, color, pythontex. I have python 3.7 installed on my computer as well.

My editor allows me to run the pycode environment without raising an error. I used the following code as a test

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
.
.
.
\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
    print("Hello World!")
\end{pycode}

Test
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Running the file outputted a pdf with the text "Test". The editor also produced these files:

1. Test.aux
2. Test.txt
3. Test.pdf
4. Test.pytxcode (pytxcode file)
5. Test.synctex (WinRAR file)
6. Test.tex

I know I am supposed to recompile my LaTex file Test after running some python code. I am not sure how to do that.

Can someone please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify your environment, and the version (s) of python installed on your machine.
On my Debian box, I just compiled as usual, I open a terminal (tools menu) and type

```
pythontex --interpreter "python: python3" <filename>.tex
```

then recompile the tex file.
To successfully compile, the python code must be error free, for example as in this file [http://ix.io/3tph`](http://ix.io/3tph%60)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do I need to specify any path variables? If I'm compiling the python code from the terminal, I would need to tell windows how to find pythontex right?

Comment: Sorry,I can't really help since I'm not a Windows user. Probably you can google on "python windows configuration". I can do that but since I'm french, it should be french documentation. Once Python 3.x configured, you can test my command.

Comment: According to the pythontex documentation, the pythontex command on a Windows box should be "pythontex --interpreter" python:py -3 <file name> ". I can't check since I'm not a Windows user.